# Soma valores com AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Estou tentando somar dois valores. Exemplo valorA 150,00 e valorB 50,00. Tentei fazer assim {{valorA + valorB}} e está retornando 150.0050. Não tem como a fazer a soma desta maneira? valorA do ng-repeat e valorB de campo input

Answer (score 1):

Isso acontece porque valorA e valorB não são números mas strings, por isso ao somar ele está na verdade concatenando seus valores.

Teria de usar algo como `{{Number(valorA) + Number(valorB)}}`

Ou converter a model direto na controller, assim: `$scope.valorA = parseFloat(valorA);`

Só atente para o formato do número, que deve ter sempre ponto como separador de decimais, e nunca vírgula.

Answer (score 0):

é bem tranquilo fazer o que você precisa.
No Javascript para trabalhar com valores float é bacana você converter o valor. 
Obs: Os valores devem ser utizando o . e não a , o ideal seria o seu valor já estiver com ponto no lugar de vírgula, por exemplo: 150.00 mas se for uma string com vírgula ex: '150,00' você pode usar um replace com um parseFloat.
Vou colocar um exemplo simples pra tentar ajudar.

```js
app = angular.module('meuapp', []);

app.controller('moduloArray', function($scope) {
    $scope.dadosArray = [{
        valor1: '138,00',
        valor2: '25,00'
    }, {
        valor1: '56,00',
        valor2: '84,00'
    }, {
        valor1: '16,00',
        valor2: '73,00'
    }];
    
    //faz o replace trocando vírgula por ponto, convertendo em float e somando os dois numeros
    $scope.calcularValor = function(v1, v2){
      return parseFloat(v1.replace(',','.'))+parseFloat(v2.replace(',','.'));
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="meuapp">
    <div ng-controller="moduloArray">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="d in dadosArray">
                <td>
                    <span ng-bind="d.valor1"></span> +
                    <span ng-bind="d.valor2"></span> =
                </td>
                <td>
                    <b ng-bind="calcularValor(d.valor1, d.valor2)"></b>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```